# WooCommerce - Show Random Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to show random WooCommerce products on a page. This is nothing to do with "featured products" just random from any category.

I've been looking but cant seem to find any plugin or script to do this? Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131808/45245) post, it should help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Alright folks here is a bit of code I am using for mine its for recent products but is doing the job. Just add to page you want to show them on.

[recent_products per_page="4" columns="4" orderby="rand" order="rand"]

Answer (score 13):

Try this. 
Paste code into functions.php
Go to wp-admin/ Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Display
View settings drop down order by random will be a new option. *note: it will be the the last option.

```
// Shop random order. View settings drop down order by Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Display
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
        $args['order'] = '';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['random_list'] = 'Random';
    return $sortby;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
<?php

    global $post; // setup_postdata will not work without this being set (outside of the foreach loop)

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 1,
        'orderby'          => 'rand',
        'post_type'        => 'product' ); 

    $random_products = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: none of these work... why is it so hard to get woocommerce to randomize products??

Answer (score 4):

You can try it. let post it in function.php

```
 add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'set_sort_order');
   function set_sort_order($args) {
     $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
     return ($args);    
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the code I used [featured_products per_page="8" columns="4" orderby="rand"]

Comment: Could you elaborate on this further? This isn't a great response to the question.

Comment: I think there is a difference we have to address, and that is that this code will work on a page you setup. But if you want to make the shop homepage work with the rand() by default, then you need to add code specifically, through something like code snippets plugin

Answer (score 1):

I just used this [products limit="8" columns="4" orderby="rand" order="rand" visibility="visible"].and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use code to make the shop homepage sort by random, then use the following code. All you need to do is install a plugin called "code snippets" that allows you to make changes in WordPress without changing any core files.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'shop_default_orderby_rand' );
function shop_default_orderby_rand( $query ) {
    if ( is_shop() && ( ! isset($_GET['orderby']) || 'menu_order' === $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
```